# iphone table view

Tags: iphone

I have a table view in iphone.when i tap a cell a new view to insert in that particular cell after that when i tap some where a view gets hide and cell content to get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a subview to the tapped cell.

UIView *SubView;

Define the subview.

[tableviewcell addSubview:SubView];

For the subview to disappear, add Gesture Recognizor for the view displayed in the cell. or you have a button to disappear the view when tapping the button.

Try it. it's simple.